# Azimuth shading

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to gradually shade a rectangle in a way that e.g. bottom edge is red and left edge is blue.

```
\fill[left color=blue,bottom color=red] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
```

Therefore colour should be changing by azimuth, like colour wheel centred in bottom left angle.  Is that possible to do?

Thanks.

Comment: What should happen at the bottom left? How can the whole of the left be blue *and* the whole of the bottom be red? What have you tried? Did you try just clipping a colour wheel shading to a rectangle? Please give a Minimum Working Example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't enjoy Postscript, it makes my head hurt. Anyway here is another linear interpolated shading. You can use it in TikZ pictures too.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading[vcol,hcol]{azimuth}{\pgfpointorigin}%
{\pgfpoint{4cm}{4cm}}{\pgfshadecolortorgb{vcol}{\mycola}\pgfshadecolortorgb{hcol}{\mycolb}}{
atan 90 div dup dup 
\mycolablue \mycolbblue sub exch mul \mycolablue exch sub 3 1 roll
\mycolagreen \mycolbgreen sub mul \mycolagreen exch sub exch 
\mycolared \mycolbred sub mul \mycolared exch sub 3 1 roll exch 
}

\begin{document}
\colorlet{vcol}{black}
\colorlet{hcol}{yellow}
\pgfuseshading{azimuth}
%
\colorlet{vcol}{red}
\colorlet{hcol}{green}
\pgfuseshading{azimuth} % Ow, colorblind highness
%
\colorlet{vcol}{white}
\colorlet{hcol}{blue}
\pgfuseshading{azimuth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An example of using this shading in TikZ pictures;

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{vcol/.code={\colorlet{vcol}{#1}},hcol/.code={\colorlet{hcol}{#1}},vcol=red,hcol=blue}
\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading[vcol,hcol]{azimuth}{\pgfpointorigin}%
{\pgfpoint{50bp}{50bp}}%
{%
\pgfshadecolortorgb{vcol}{\mycola}%
\pgfshadecolortorgb{hcol}{\mycolb}
}{%
atan 90 div dup dup 
\mycolablue \mycolbblue sub mul \mycolablue exch sub 3 1 roll
\mycolagreen \mycolbgreen sub mul \mycolagreen exch sub exch 
\mycolared \mycolbred sub mul \mycolared exch sub 3 1 roll exch 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shading=azimuth]
% Start modern art
\shade[vcol=yellow,hcol=black] (0,0) rectangle (5,3);
\shade[vcol=red!50!yellow,hcol=blue!80!purple!70!black] (-3,0) circle (1.5);
\shade[vcol=orange,hcol=green!50!blue] (-3,0) ++ (150:3.5) -- ++(150:1cm) 
                                       arc (150:90:4.5cm) coordinate(a)
                                       --++(-40:3cm)|-++(0,-2cm)
                                       arc (20:110:3cm)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that, in the complicated paths, there is some serious clipping, scaling and translation going on. So this would best work on squares. Also this is very likely to upset your printer since many of them will have an incompatible PS interpreter. Test those pages first.  And yes, I'm colorblind so nevermind the examples.

Comment: I don't quite get it.  Can I fill a square with azumuth shading?

Comment: @Pygmalion My bad. I'll add an example later when I have time. The answer is yes.

Comment: @Pygmalion Added more TikZ syntax examples.

Comment: Great!  This solves my other question too, so I will delete it!

Comment: I have chosen this solution, because it is (a) fast and (b) easily adaptable to various problems.  I don't understand a single line of  code, though :)

Comment: @Pygmalion Can't say I understand either :) Try to print it once though. I'm not sure if it's proper PS syntax.

Comment: I hope this does not mean I will have problems using your solution...

Comment: @Pygmalion I've had some problems with some printers but newer ones were ok so I don't know exactly if it is bulletproof

Answer (score 11):

A possible way: fake the gradient by drawing lots of thin triangles in solid colors which smoothly change their color from red to blue. The resulting "disc" can be clipped to a rectangle, as the following example shows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[clip] (0,0) rectangle (1,0.7);
\foreach \i in {0,0.5,...,90} {
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\shade}{100/(90-0)*\i}
  \fill[draw=none,blue!\shade!red] (0:0) -- (\i:1.4) -- (\i+1:1.4) -- cycle;
}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,0.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Nice solution. :)

Comment: +1, that is sooo clever!

Answer (score 11):

Another approach, using PGFPlots to draw a surface plot:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    view={0}{90},
    hide axis,
    axis equal image,
    xmax=pi, ymax=pi,
    samples y=6,
    colormap={redblue}{color(0cm)=(red); color(1cm)=(blue)}
]
\addplot3 [
    surf, shader=interp,
    domain=0:90,
    y domain=0:2*pi,
    data cs=polar
] (x,y,x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

This makes it possible to specify other color gradients. For instance, you can get a gradient that starts at red, goes to yellow at 30 degrees, and then to blue:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    view={0}{90},
    hide axis,
    axis equal image,
    xmax=pi, ymax=pi,
    samples y=6, samples=60,
    colormap={redyellowblue}{color(0cm)=(red); color(0.33333cm)=(yellow); color(1cm)=(blue)}
]
\addplot3 [
    surf, shader=interp,
    domain=0:90,
    y domain=0:2*pi,
    data cs=polar
] (x,y,x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Smart one! Like it

Comment: I actually need this shading as a part of one pgfplot.  Is it possible to do that without starting pgfplot within pgfplot?

Comment: @Pygmalion: That depends on your use case. Could you start a new question with an example?

Comment: I did as you proposed: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197910/azimuth-shading-for-phase-diagram

Comment: @Pygmalion: I was just about to post an answer to that question, but now it's deleted.. `=(`

Comment: Sorry.  I thought you gave up.  I un-deleted it.