# Azimuth shading for phase diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make a phase diagram plot.  As seen below, liquid phase (blue) changes gradually into gas phase (red).  I want to fill the white part of the graph with azimuth shading between red and blue.

There are already few solutions how to make azimuth shading here

[Azimuth shading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197864/azimuth-shading)

but I do not know how to apply it to this problem.  **In particular, how can I force azimuth shading to fill only empty space on my plot?**

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xmin=0,ymin=0,xmax=3,ymax=2]
\addplot[name path=gas,very thick] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,1.5)};
\addplot[name path=liq,very thick] coordinates {(1,1) (1,2.1) (2,2.1)};
\addplot[name path=help1] coordinates {(2,2) (0,2) (0,0)};
\addplot[name path=help2] coordinates {(0,0) (3,0) (3,1.5)};

\addplot[blue] fill between[of=gas and liq];
\addplot[green] fill between[of=liq and help1];
\addplot[red] fill between[of=gas and help2];

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see you were asked to start a new question so perhaps it would be better to say that it is not clear how this question is different. For example, it is really unclear whether you've tried to use one of those answers and what particular problems you've encountered.

Comment: I rephrased and bolded the most important part.  Is that better?

Comment: @cfr In any case it's a valid question and clearly not a duplicate.

Comment: @percusse It is much clearer than it was, though. It was not at all obvious to me that it was not a duplicate in its initial form. (I'm not saying it was. But it wasn't clear to me, at least, how it was not.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had problems with adapting Jake's solution to my actual phase diagram, but succeeded to adapt percusse's solution from the previous thread

[Azimuth shading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197864/azimuth-shading)

It includes a lot of postscripting I don't understand a bit, but it works on *arbitrary* area.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\tikzset{vcol/.code={\colorlet{vcol}{#1}},hcol/.code={\colorlet{hcol}{#1}},vcol=red,hcol=blue}
\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading[vcol,hcol]{azimuth}{\pgfpointorigin}%
{\pgfpoint{50bp}{50bp}}%
{%
\pgfshadecolortorgb{vcol}{\mycola}%
\pgfshadecolortorgb{hcol}{\mycolb}
}{%
atan 90 div dup dup 
\mycolablue \mycolbblue sub mul \mycolablue exch sub 3 1 roll
\mycolagreen \mycolbgreen sub mul \mycolagreen exch sub exch 
\mycolared \mycolbred sub mul \mycolared exch sub 3 1 roll exch 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{semilogyaxis}[xmin=0,ymin=1e0,xmax=3,ymax=1e2,axis on top]

\addplot[name path=gas,very thick] coordinates {(0,1) (1,10) (2,32)};
\addplot[name path=liq,very thick] coordinates {(1,10) (1,126) (2,126)};
\addplot[name path=help1] coordinates {(2,100) (0,100) (0,1)};
\addplot[name path=help2] coordinates {(0,1) (3,1) (3,32)};

\addplot[blue] fill between[of=gas and liq];
\addplot[green] fill between[of=liq and help1];
\addplot[red] fill between[of=gas and help2];
\shade[shading=azimuth,vcol=blue,hcol=red] (axis cs:2,32) rectangle (axis cs:3,100);

\end{semilogyaxis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's how you can use the [PGFPlots approach from your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197882/2552).

I still use the `data cs:polar` key, even though we're in a cartesian coordinate system, and shift the shaded plot using `shift={(data cs:2,1.5)}`. That yields a nicer gradient than specifying the surface plot using cartesian coordinates.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xmin=0,ymin=0,xmax=3,ymax=2, zmin=0, zmax=2,view={0}{90}, axis equal image]
\addplot3 [
    colormap={redblue}{
        color(0cm)=(red);
        color(0.2cm)=(red!85!blue);
        color(0.4cm)=(red!50!blue);
        color(0.6cm)=(red!15!blue);
        color(1cm)=(blue)},
    surf, shader=interp,
    domain=0:90,
    data cs=polar, 
    y domain=0:2,
    shift={(axis cs:2,1.5)}
] (x,y,x);

\addplot[name path=gas,very thick] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,1.5)};
\addplot[name path=liq,very thick] coordinates {(1,1) (1,2.1) (2,2.1)};
\addplot[name path=help1] coordinates {(2,2) (0,2) (0,0)};
\addplot[name path=help2] coordinates {(0,0) (3,0) (3,1.5)};

\addplot[blue] fill between[of=gas and liq];
\addplot[green] fill between[of=liq and help1];
\addplot[red] fill between[of=gas and help2];
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

To use a semilog axis, you can use the same approach, just be aware that the radial unit is now also logarithmic:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    ymode=log,
    xmin=0,
    ymin=1e0,
    xmax=3,
    ymax=1e2,
    zmin=0,
    zmax=2,
    view={0}{90}
]
\addplot3 [
    colormap={redblue}{
        color(0cm)=(red);
        color(0.2cm)=(red!85!blue);
        color(0.4cm)=(red!50!blue);
        color(0.6cm)=(red!15!blue);
        color(1cm)=(blue)},
    surf, shader=interp,
    domain=0:90,
    data cs=polar, 
    y domain=1:10,
    shift={(axis cs:2,32)}
] (x,y,x);

\addplot[name path=gas,very thick] coordinates {(0,1) (1,10) (2,32)};
\addplot[name path=liq,very thick] coordinates {(1,10) (1,126) (2,126)};
\addplot[name path=help1] coordinates {(2,100) (0,100) (0,1)};
\addplot[name path=help2] coordinates {(0,1) (3,1) (3,32)};

\addplot[blue] fill between[of=gas and liq];
\addplot[green] fill between[of=liq and help1];
\addplot[red] fill between[of=gas and help2];
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is really nice solution!  However, when I was creating MWE, I forgot that y axis should be log axis (semilogyaxis) - as always in case of phase diagrams.  Can this solution be modified for semilogyaxis too?  Thanks!

Comment: @Pygmalion: That should be possible, I'll try to come up with something tomorrow. As a side note: phase diagrams do not always have a logarithmic pressure axis. Take a look at the diagrams in [Phase Diagrams of the Elements](http://books.google.de/books?id=F2HVYh6wLBcC&printsec=frontcover), for instance.

Comment: @Pygmalion: I've edited my answer to show how to use this approach for a semilog axis.