# Apply polar transformation to a shaded rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, shading, transformation

## Update

How can I get the shade to vary in the theta direction of the transformed figure rather than left to right? I was hoping the left to right shading in the original rectangle would become a shading in the increasing theta direction!
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\usepgfmodule[nonlineartransformations]

\makeatletter
\def\polartransformation
{
    % \pgf@x will contain the radius
    % \pgf@y will contain the distance
    \pgfmathsincos@{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@x}%
    % pgfmathresultx is now the cosine of radius and
    % pgfmathresulty is the sine of radius
    \pgf@x=\pgfmathresultx\pgf@y%
    \pgf@y=\pgfmathresulty\pgf@y%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw [black, left color=white, right color=gray ] (3,1) rectangle (7.5,2);
    {
        \pgftransformnonlinear{\polartransformation}
        \pgfsettransformnonlinearflatness{2pt}
        \draw [black, left color=white, right color=gray ] (3,1) rectangle (7.5,2);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Original Problem:

I simply wish to transform this shaded region into an annular one using a polar coordinated transformation. The resulting shaded region should be an annular slice  illustrated in the simple diagram (sorry for poor quality). I want the shading to maintain its "orientation". The rectangle is created in the tikz code below with most code taken from the PGF manual.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\usepgfmodule[nonlineartransformations]

\def\polartransformation
{
    % \pgf@x will contain the radius
    % \pgf@y will contain the distance
    \pgfmathsincos@{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@x}%
    % pgfmathresultx is now the cosine of radius and
    % pgfmathresulty is the sine of radius
    \pgf@x=\pgfmathresultx\pgf@y%
    \pgf@y=\pgfmathresulty\pgf@y%
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[black] (0:20mm) arc [start angle=0,end angle = 90, radius=2cm];
    {
        \pgftransformnonlinear{\polartransformation}
        \pgfsettransformnonlinearflatness{2pt}
        \draw [black, left color=white, right color=gray ] (3,3) rectangle (4,3.5);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But here I get the error:

```
Missing number, treated as zero. ...left color=white, right color=gray ] (3,3)
```

Comment: This is given in the manual with `polartransformation` in the nonlinear transformations section

Comment: OK I will check that - so basically I should be able to define my rectangle in a scope and then apply the transformation to it?

Comment: @Cragfelt I think the link may be wrong?

Comment: You need to add `\makeatletter`before the definition and `\makeatother` after the definition of `polartransformation` to make it work since the macros involve `@` character

Comment: @percusse  Ah perfect thank you very much for your input, that solved it!

Comment: @Jack You are right, the correct link is this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119911/plot-basic-complex-transformation-in-latex

Comment: I updated my question to focus on the shading part now that I can do the transformation

Comment: If it is not a predefined shading then you need to write your own unfortunately such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197864/azimuth-shading

Comment: @percusse I see! Im a tikz noob but I would have thought that if the shading of the rectangle is defined as a type of contour plot then applying a transform to that will do what I want... Maybe there is a work around.

Comment: Shadings are *seen through* the area defined by the area of the current path. So when you change the shape of the path that you *look through* it won't change the shading. You have to transform the shading too.